# A question about conditional probability distribution

Tags: probability

Given that $X=(X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n)$ is a random vector on $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathscr{B}^n, P)$ and $X \sim N(0,D)$ ($n$-dimensional normal distribution). Let $Y=xD^{-1}x',x\in \mathbb R^n$ and find the conditional probability distribution of $X$ under $\sigma(Y)$.

I want to get the conditional mathematical expectation, and we know there is a Borel-measurable function $g$ s.t. $E(X \mid \sigma(Y))=g(Y)$, then for all $A \in \sigma(Y)$, we have the equation $$\int_A X \,\mathrm{d}P=\int_A g(Y) \,\mathrm{d}P_{σ(Y)}.$$For some specific $A$, maybe I can calculate their derivatives to get $g(Y)$ and get the conditional probability distribution of $X$ under $\sigma(Y)$.But it seems to have failed. I still don't know how to solve it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please help me.

Comment: FYI, the conditional expectation says (almost) nothing about the conditional distribution. Are you after the latter or the former?

Comment: I want to get its conditional distribution, but I don't know how to get it. So I think I can find its conditional expectation first.

Comment: You may. And it does not help in the slightestt.